# How to slice pandas DataFrame by disjunction statement (logical "or")?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to slice a `pandas.DataFrame` which satisfies condition A **or** condition B. Most of the search results only show how to slice dataframe using **"and"**. So I wonder if it is possible to use **"or"** operator without converting (A and B) to (not (not A and not B))? Because sometimes there are many "or" conditions needed, and converting might be troublesome.

I tried to use:

```
df[(df['c1']==x1) or (df['c2']==x2)]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: The way the slicing works is it iterates over each cell and checks the truth value, so any logical statement can go inside the []

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the logical or symbol `|`

```
df[(df['c1'] == x1) | (df['c2'] == x2)]
```

For `and`, you would need to use `&`

```
df[(df['c1'] == x1) & (df['c2'] == x2)]
```

Comment: Really it's the bitwise or symbol, but the logical `or` can't be overloaded due to short-circuiting problems, so Pandas had to use `|` instead.